# Convert a List of Dictionaries into a Dictionary of Tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-2.6, dictionary

How do I convert a List of Dictionaries that looks something like this:

```
[{'id':2, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':1, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':32,'risk':'aa'},
 {'id':2, 'risk':'aa'}, 
 {'id':7, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':7, 'risk':'b'}]
```

into a Dictionary of Tuples that will look like this after sorting:

```
{1:('a', ), 2:('a','aa'), 7:('a','b'), 32:('aa', )}
```

Comment: Fixed your single tuples, remember `('a')` is not actually a tuple, that's just using parenthesis to group the string `'a'`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to automatically create the tuples, then just iterate over the `list_of_dicts`:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id':2, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':1, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':32,'risk':'aa'},
 {'id':2, 'risk':'aa'}, 
 {'id':7, 'risk':'a'}, 
 {'id':7, 'risk':'b'}]

from collections import defaultdict

dict_of_tuples = defaultdict(tuple)

for dct in list_of_dicts:
    dict_of_tuples[dct['id']] += (dct['risk'],)
```

Which results in:

```
>>> dict_of_tuples
defaultdict(<type 'tuple'>, {32: ('aa',), 1: ('a',), 2: ('a', 'aa'), 7: ('a', 'b')})
```

If you then want a sorted dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(dict_of_tuples.items()))
OrderedDict([(1, ('a',)), (2, ('a', 'aa')), (7, ('a', 'b')), (32, ('aa',))])
```

Comment: That is Returning an Error for me:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dict_to_Tuples.py", line 13, in <module>
    dict_of_tuples[dct['id']] += dct['risk']
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Comment: Note that `OrderedDict` is only in 2.7, and the OP is using 2.6

Comment: @user1793317 you forgot to make it into a tuple `(dict['risk'],)`

Comment: You need `dict_of_tuples[dct['id']] += (dct['risk'],)` as posted in the answer. Notice the `()` around `dct['risk']`

Answer (score 3):

The [*dict.setdefault*](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method makes short work of this kind of problem:

```
>>> lod = [{'id':2, 'risk':'a'}, 
           {'id':1, 'risk':'a'}, 
           {'id':32,'risk':'aa'},
           {'id':2, 'risk':'aa'}, 
           {'id':7, 'risk':'a'}, 
           {'id':7, 'risk':'b'}]
>>> dot = {}
>>> for d in lod:
        idnum, risk = d['id'], d['risk']
        dot.setdefault(idnum, []).append(risk)

>>> dot
{32: ['aa'], 1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'aa'], 7: ['a', 'b']}
```

You can also use *collections.defaultdict* to create the same effect, but that doesn't create a regular dictionary and it requires an understanding of factory functions and zero argument constructors.

Comment: +1 for avoiding O(n^2) concatenations of tuples. They can always be converted at the end if it's really needed

Answer (score 2):

Generally people forget to use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method in similar situations. So with basic python functions:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'id':2, 'risk':'a'}, 
    {'id':1, 'risk':'a'}, 
    {'id':32,'risk':'aa'},
    {'id':2, 'risk':'aa'}, 
    {'id':7, 'risk':'a'}, 
    {'id':7, 'risk':'b'}]

final_dict = {}

for item in list_of_dicts:
    final_dict[item['id']] = final_dict.get(item['id'], tuple()) + (item['risk'],)


>> {1: ('a',), 2: ('a', 'aa'), 7: ('a', 'b'), 32: ('aa',)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it in a longer way. Not as neat as agf's solution, but it works

```
new_dict = {}
for x in my_dict_list: 
    m = new_dict.get(x['id'],())
    m += (x['risk'],)
    new_dict[x['id']] = m
```

Input

```
my_dict_list = [{'id':2, 'risk':'a'}, 
                {'id':1, 'risk':'a'}, 
                {'id':32,'risk':'aa'},
                {'id':2, 'risk':'aa'}, 
                {'id':7, 'risk':'a'}, 
                {'id':7, 'risk':'b'}]
```

Output

```
>>> new_dict
{32: ('aa',), 1: ('a',), 2: ('a', 'aa'), 7: ('a', 'b')}
```

Comment: You can change this to create tuples, and then you won't need the second `for` loop. `new_dict[x['id']] = (x['risk'],)` in the `if`, and in the `else`, `new_dict[x['id']] += (x['risk'],)`